# Is java's File class' object serializable?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, file-io, serializable

I am working on a project, it requires to send directory information from one client to another on a network. so tell me, can i get this information on another client by only sending File class' object? please explain me the reason for your YES or NO.

**Updated Question**

i am posting the code which i have tried....

The Client Code:-

```
public class FileClient{
    public static void main(String str[]){
        try{
            Socket sock = new Socket("10.16.10.82",4000);

                    /* Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4000); */ //for localhost 
            File f = new File("MyFile.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            os.writeObject(f);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            System.out.println("object sent");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

And The following is the server code:-

```
class FileServer{
    public static void main(String str[]){
        try{
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(4000);
            while(true){
                Socket cs = sock.accept();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
                File f = (File)in.readObject();
                System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
                System.out.println(f.length()+" bytes read");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

this works fine if i run server on localhost but when i use two different machines one for client and other for server the output is different (it shows 0 bytes read). it seems right because the actual file is not available at remote server. i am confused about File class' field i.e.,

```
static private FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getFileSystem() //see javadoc for File
```

what exact information server is getting after reading the File object?

Comment: Based on the [JavaDocs for `File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), yes.  Having said that, I would greatly discourage sending `File` over the wire as it is contextual to the local machine.  It would be better to devise your own class which carried the information you need - IMHO

Comment: Also, why didn't you just to and use a `ObjectOutputStream` and try writing a `File` object out to disk and see what happened?

Comment: thanks a lot, i will definitely try this. why would not i thought that :-)

Comment: More to the point, why didn't you look in the Javdoc? It's pointless asking Internet questions on matters that are already documented. Just a complete waste of time.

Comment: FYI, a `File` object is little more than a thin wrapper around a file path.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried writing a 'File' object to another client using 'ObjectOutputStream' but it didn't work.... it looks i have to make my own class.

Comment: @Anubhav Really, I did a small write test it worked fine for me...

Comment: @EJP you didn't read the details i provided.... i read the java docs before posting the question. Every question is worthwhile, whether it's a silly one.

Comment: @Anubhav And I was able to read it.  Don't know if that means it will go over the wire though...

Comment: i have edited the question with code.... please go through it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can send information using the `File` class reference because it implements the `Serializable` interface.

For more details, read Java's `File` [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

### Code example

You can achieve it by following code:

```
String sourcePathFilename = "path.txt";
try {
    File file = new File(sourcePathFilename);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String targetpath);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```